# Bootstrap (2.3.1) + SimpleForm (2.1) inline label for radio button group

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button, label, simple-form

I'm trying to create inline radio buttons which also has its label inline (at the very left).

As I state in the title, using Bootstrap and SimpleForm.

My code looks like this:

```
<%= f.input :breakdown_or_size, 
            :collection => ["Breakdown", "Manual"],
            :as => :radio_buttons, 
            :item_wrapper_class => 'inline',
            :label => 'Select One: ' %>
```

This is what I get:

[image: radio buttons below label]
<sub>(source: [webpagescreenshot.info](http://www.webpagescreenshot.info/i3/516f8dbc4c7633-60839289))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I looked high and low for simple_form_for help. In the end I couldn't find anything, but at least with form_for you can do this:

```
<%= form_for(@book) do |f| %>
  <% if @book.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@book.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this book from being saved:</h2>

    <ul>
    <% @book.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>

<div class="actions", style='inline'>

  <%= f.label 'Select One: ' %>
  <br/>
  <%= f.radio_button :collection, "Breakdown" %> Breakdown
  <%= f.radio_button :collection, "Manual" %> Manual
  <br/>
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
```

Which at least solves the inline rendering.